# css solution for responsive SVG chart (polyline coordinates)

Tags: svg, charts, responsive, polyline

I'm using javascript to generate the points coordinates of a `polyline` element inside a line chart. The chart must have a fixed height (`210px`) and a responsive width (always `100%` of its parent div).

Problem is the points coordinates of the polyline don't change when resizing the window.

Is there a way to set the coordinates of the `polyline` as percentage of its parent `div` so that the horizontal coordinates change when resizing the window ?

I know I could use javascript to listen for window resize and recalculate the points coordinates of the polyline but it seems somewhat overkill so I was hoping there was a lighter, pure CSS solution.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Hal_9100/1cnq389g/

Comment: Not sure what you want. Have you tried viewBox="0 0 350 210" on the svg element?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `viewBox` to your SVG.  If you want the graph to stretch horizontally, to fit the box, then you'll also want to add a suitable `preserveAspectRatio` value.

```css
* {padding: 0; margin: 0;}

#container {
    width: 60%; height: 210px;
    background: #fff;
}
svg {
    width: 100%; height: 210px;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 450 210" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <polyline id="myLine" fill="none" stroke="#2681DC" stroke-width="2" points="0,210 50,67 100,174 150,198 200,202 250,190 300,205 350,207 400,198 450,19 "></polyline>
    </svg>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1cnq389g/2/